# How do I get the response time in rest assured?

Tags: rest, rest-assured

Unable to get the response time in rest assured?  I have used the getTime()  method but didn't help

Comment: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#measuring-response-time

Answer (score 1):

I do not know which `RestAssured` version you are using, but starting with `2.8.0` and greater you have a rather simple approach by using the [`getTime` method on the `Response` object](https://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.2.0/io/restassured/response/ResponseOptions.html#getTime--).

So just try the following and please verify that it is working for you:

```
long millis = RestAssured.get("http://google.de").time()
```

Further details about time measuring and the use of time constraints in assertions can also be found in the [respective part of the RestAssured docs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#measuring-response-time).

If you're still on an older version than `2.8.0`, consider upgrading, it is really worth it!

Answer (score 1):

In this code snippet you can define the time unit as well.

```
long actualTimeWithUnits=given().get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/currency/cop").getTimeIn(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```